# Get photos from twitter home timeline API

Tags: api, twitter

Anyone know if it's possible to grab all posts with an image, from the Twitter API?
I know I can check all tweets for a media, but that's a bit slow process.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to include `include_entities=true` as part of the request:

i.e. https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&include_entities=true

Then, look for any `media_url` elements; those will contain the URL to any photos. It may contain video links, so you'll have to filter for common image types (**.png**/ **.jpg**/ **.gif**/etc).

Answer (score 0):

As well as `include_entities=true`, you can use `filter:images` to request only tweets that include images. But that only seems to work on a search request, not a timeline request. Hope it helps anyway.